# Way to figure out if SqlBulkCopy operation inserted values or not

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I have a SqlBulkCopy method that does inserts. The destination table to which it does inserts has a Unique Key constraint defined, so the bulk copy does not insert duplicates. But since the restriction is only at the database level, I am not able to programmatically verify if the insert was done or not. Here is my method:

```
string connect = "user id=*********; password=*******; server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=*********;";
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connect, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.BaseTermPrice";
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("BaseID", "BaseID");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ContractDate", "ContractDate");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TermID", "TermID");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Price", "Price");
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PeakType", "PeakType");
        try
        {
            // Write from the source to the destination.
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[0]);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            success = false;
            logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
            logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

There is no exception from here when no insert takes place. How will I determine this so that I can inform the user he is trying to insert duplicates?

My Unique Key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BaseTermPrice] ADD  CONSTRAINT [UK_BaseTermPrice] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
[BaseID] ASC,
[ContractDate] ASC,
[TermID] ASC,
[PeakType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: the SqlBulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied Event might be useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What happens if you try to insert a duplicate row according to that constraint?

Comment: Here is the response I got in SSMS:
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_BaseTermPrice'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BaseTermPrice'.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no exception from here when no insert takes place.

Did you make a unique index `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`? This is bad practice because it hides data errors.

If this option is false, a bulk insert operation *will* throw an exception. If it seems it does not, then your error logging is broken. Set the debugger to break on all exceptions.

Comment: I have added my Unique Key Constraint where I see `Ignore_Dup_key = off`. So is probably the debugger? How do I make it break on all exceptions?

Comment: Google how to do it.; Manually insert two obviously duplicate rows using SSMS. You should be getting an error. Are you?

Comment: Yes, of course I get an error. When I do a ParametrizedQuery Insert or a direct insert through SSMS.

Comment: Ok, that means the index is working. Probably the data you're bulk inserting is not what you expect. Add debugging code: clear the data table and manually add two rows that obviously conflict. If now you don't get an error this would be really puzzling. Again, set your debugger to break on all exceptions.

Comment: I did set the debugger as specified. Still no errors. I just did a Parametrized Insert and an exception was duly thrown.

Comment: Can you post the exact code that you used to try to force a duplicate key error with SqlBulkCopy? Maybe we can spot something. This is a hard bug to catch.

Comment: :I am sorry, but it was a programming issue. I was handling the exception and returning true from there and the debugger did not break on exception for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the things I suspected. That's why I was digging in that direction. I guess you found the issue because forcing an error did not result in an error output.

Comment: Yes. The insert takes place in a Web service and I was calling it from an add-in so the debugger was not very helpful as I could not step into the service.